# NodeJS NPM soap - how do I chain async methods without callbacks (ie use async or Promise)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, soap

I have successfully called a sequence of soap webservice methods using nodejs/javascript, but using callbacks... right now it looks something like this:

```
soap.createClient(wsdlUrl, function (err, soapClient) {
    console.log("soap.createClient();");
    if (err) {
        console.log("error", err);
    }
    soapClient.method1(soaprequest1, function (err, result, raw, headers) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Security_Authenticate error", err);
        }
        soapClient.method2(soaprequest2, function (err, result, raw, headers) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log("Air_MultiAvailability error", err);
                }
                //etc... 
        });
    });

});
```

I'm trying to get to something cleaner using Promise or async, similar to this (based on the example in the docs here https://www.npmjs.com/package/soap) :

```
var soap = require('soap');

soap.createClientAsync(wsdlURL)
    .then((client) => {
        return client.method1(soaprequest1);
    })
    .then((response) => {
        return client.method2(soaprequest2);
    });//... etc
```

My issue is that in the latter example, the soap client is no longer accessible after the first call and it typically returns a 'not defined' error...

is there a 'clean' way of carrying an object through this kind of chaining to be used/accessible in subsequent calls ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to keep the chain of promises flat, you can assign the instance of soap to a variable in the outer scope:

```
let client = null;

soap.createClientAsync(wsdlURL)
  .then((instance) => {
    client = instance
  })
  .then(() => {
    return client.method1(soaprequest2);
  })
  .then((response) => {
    return client.method2(soaprequest2);
  });
```

Another option would be nested chain method calls after the client is resolved:

```
soap.createClientAsync(wsdlURL)
  .then((client) => {
    Promise.resolve()
      .then(() => {
        return client.method1(soaprequest2);
      })
      .then((response) => {
        return client.method2(soaprequest2);
      });
  })
```

Answer (score 16):

Use `async/await` syntax.

```js
const soap = require('soap');

(async () => {
const client = await soap.createClientAsync(wsdlURL);
cosnt response = await client.method1Async(soaprequest1);
await method2(soaprequest2);
})();
```

Pay attention to `Async` on both `createClient` and `method1`

Comment: This should have been the chosen answer.